# How to make the script automated to take password on its own?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, password, sftp

I have a script that is doing `sftp` some files from one server to another, like inside the script `script.ksh` I have the below lines;

```
sftp user@ip_address << EOF
cd path
put file1
bye
EOF
```

When I am running the script like;

```
./script.ksh
```

It is asking for password like below;

```
Password:
```

Here I have to pass the password manually as this is not a password less connection.

I want to make this script automated, that when the `Password` prompt will occur, then it should take the password on its own. Can anyone have any suggestion please.

Comment: sshpass is also an option

Comment: @Naitree please can you let me know where and how to use this `sshpass` command in my script?

Comment: If security is not a concern, just prepend `sshpass -p password` before your `sftp` command. That should do it.

Comment: @Naitree Thanks for your help, but I checked in my unix box `sshpass` is not installed, I also don't have a privilege to install it. Do you have any other idea other than `sshpass`? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, you have to install something or use ssh key.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn sftp USERNAME@ip_address:/path/to/folder
expect "Password:"
send "PASSWORD\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "put file1\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\n"
```

or if you don't want to dedicate the whole script to expect:

```
#!/bin/sh

expect << 'EOS'
spawn sftp USERNAME@ip_address:/path/to/folder
expect "Password:"
send "PASSWORD\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "put file1\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\n"
EOS
```

Comment: I just noticed this was a question from a year ago...

Answer (score 2):

By design ssh doesn't allow 'embedding' of passwords - that's because it has a mechanism for non-interactive auth using public-private key pairs.

So I would suggest you consider that as your first port of call. Usually it's as simple as:

- run `ssh-keygen` on your client.
- add the `id_rsa.pub` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on your server.

If that's not an option for some reason, then the fallback option is `expect` which allows you to do send a password to ssh.

Comment: Hey Sob, sorry that I can't make the server password less. As I am working in a production environment, so I don't have that privilege to do this. So you want me to use `expect`. Can you please show me how to use this in my script?

Comment: Ssh key pairs are better for prod, because they are more secure.  You should talk to your sysadmi.

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy.  Especially if the /etc/hosts file contains the IP and name of the other server.

First, generate a public key that can be shared with the other computer.

```
ssh-keygen
```

Just press enter to the three questions.

Then, append your public key to the other server like so:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host
```

where remote-host can be either the name from your /etc/hosts file or the IP address.

It will prompt you to accept the other host's key - you answer yes (not just y)
Then it will prompt you for the other server's password.

That's it.  Your key has now been appended to the remote-host's .ssh/authorized_key file.

To use it, just run scp or ssh as normal and you will see that it no longer prompts you for the paswsword of remote-host.

Comment: How is this different to [an answer already given](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199721/100397)?

Comment: The only answer close is @sobrique but the ssh-copy-id -i command was omitted.  It requires doing more research to find out how to add the public key.  My answer just plain shows the two commands that need to be run.  Short and sweet, and it works.  No need for expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the lftp command:

```
lftp -u USERNAME,PASSWORD sftp://IP_ADDRESS << EOF
cd path
put file1
bye
EOF
```

Answer (score -2):

```sh
echo "ftping files to destination"
USER='(username)'
PASSWD='(********)'
sftp user@ip_address << EOF
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd path
put file1
bye
EOF
```

Comment: That looks suspiciously like FTP.

Answer (score -3):

I have think that you can use scp command

You should create a ssh key. [How to generate a key](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)

Now,  you can copy the files in other server.

```
scp file user@server.com:/path/
```

I hope that it work

Comment: Is there any other method? because I can't make the connection password less. I don't have the permission to do that. I want that, while connecting it should ask password, and then automatically the script will take the password to login in.

Comment: If you don't have permission to do password less auth, what makes you think that bypassing that is a good idea?