# Transfer file from remote server to my server via sftp in bash script

Tags: sftp

I wanna transfer a big file (1.3G) from remote server to my server via sftp/ftp in bash script (not in separated commands).

Just for instance: my server IP is 10.10.10.1 and remote server is 10.10.10.2
I connect to remote server with sftp root/123456 (user + pass).

Let me know for more information.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, allowing remote login to root isn’t considered best practice.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
        file=$(ls -ltr | tail -1)
         if [ -f $file ] ; then
         scp 
        [[root@]172.17.170.133:]drive_d/AlphaVersion/NotOfficialVersions/Windows/ 
                [[root@]172.17.233.227:]/root
     fi
I tried that script but while running it asked me to enter a password...I want to enter password inside script...Is it possible?

Comment: You can use SSH keys to not have to enter a password when running the script. Otherwise, you would probably need to use something like `expect`.

Answer (score 1):

`sftp` can read commands from either standard input or from a "batch file".

For example, to get a file from the remote host, you would use the `get` command:

```
echo 'get /path/to/file' | sftp user@10.10.10.2
```

Or, you could use a here-document to pass the command(s) to `sftp`:

```
sftp user@10.10.10.2 <<'END'
get /path/to/file
END
```

Or you could have the same `get` command in a file that you refer to with the `-b` command line option of `sftp`:

```
sftp -b somefile user@10.10.10.2
```

The file or files that you transfer to the local system would be put into the current directory (unless this is changed with `lcd`, "local `cd`", in the commands that you send to `sftp`).

To connect without having to give a password, arrange with public and private SSH keys as described in "[How to make the script automated to take password on its own?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199718/how-to-make-the-script-automated-to-take-password-on-its-own)".  Note that a remote system may well have disabled SSH access for the root user (this is a sane way to configure an SSH server).

Comment: I wanna do it with bash script not via commands and without asking me for a password.

Comment: @ShalevSason This is what I have shown. You would put the command in a script and run it with `bash`.  The link at the end of my answer points to a question regarding setting up SSH with password-less access.

Comment: but after run this command Linux asked me for sftp password....How can I insert the password to the script?

Comment: @ShalevSason You would follow the advice in the answers to the other question that I linked to at the end of my answer, or read any of the [countless other questions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com+sftp+without+password) about the same thing.

Comment: Great! I've managed to do it. BTW - do you know how to get the last updated file from folder? I mean what to add to "get" commands that will give me only the latest file from a folder?

Comment: @ShalevSason This is not possible to do with `sftp` in a reliable way.  It has no built-in functionality to do this.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to do it without remote server? It means how to copy the latest file from folder to another folder in same server in bash script? i did this command but is bash script is not valid: "$!/usr/bin
cp$(ls -t /drive_d/AlphaVersion/NotOfficialVersions/Windows | head -1) /drive_d/AlphaVersion/NotOfficialVersions/windows_latest"

Comment: @ShalevSason Please see [How do I copy the latest file from one directory to another?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/195304) and also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers  Please note that all your followup questions already have answers on this site. We also strongly discourage follow-up questions in comments.